# Good way to write combination of conditions

Tags: java, enums, logical-operators

I have a few ENUMs that for each pair combination of them something must be done. For example I have:

```
public enum Rank {
    High, 
    MID, 
    LOW
}
```

and

```
public enum Time {
    BEFORE, 
    NOW, 
    AFTER
}
```

Now in my application I need to write something like this:

```
if ( X == Rank.HIGH && Y == Time.NOW ) {
 // Do something
}
```

This works, but as the list of items in my ENUMs gets bigger those combinations are cumbersome to write. Is there any better way?

Comment: What do you need it for?

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ, sorry, fixed it.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ, Can I have another enum that holds something like this: `Rank.HIGH, Time.NOW, TRUE`

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ, That's more readable if you have all of the configuration at one place.

Comment: Will you be adding more values to each enumerable or will you be adding more enumerables?  Perhaps you could write methods, ie `private boolean isHighNow(X,Y) { return X == Rank.HIGH && Y == Time.NOW }`  This will at least contribute to readability.

Comment: @turbo, I'll add more values. So the `Rank` will be something like `High`, `Low`, `Mid` and `Zero`.

Answer (score 1):

maybe introduce one class containing all conditions?

```
public class MyEvent {
    Rank rank;
    Mytime time;

    public boolean equals(..
```

Comment: This is good. Was thinking about it. Thanks. I'll accept it if I don't get any better.